Seeking Confirmation on Latin Phrase Translation
I am reaching out to seek confirmation on a specific Latin phrase. I have come across the sentence "UNUS PERCENT MELIUS COTIDIE," which is intended to mean "one percent better every day," inspired by the concept from James Clear's book Atomic Habits.
Could you please confirm if this sentence is grammatically correct in Latin? If there are any inaccuracies, I would greatly appreciate your guidance on the correct form.
Thank you for your help!

Is the phrase meant to be adjectival or adverbial? That is, what is being described as 'better': a person? a thing? an action?

Since this looks like a tattoo, I thought it would be worthwhile to mention clearly: This is definitely incorrect.

"PERCENT" is not even a Latin word. Ancient Romans didn't have the concept of percentage as modern people use, if you want literal "percent", or say, "one hundredth", the word for it is (pars) centesima.
